# perl equal strings comparison returns false even when they are equal

Tags: perl

i have this script that its goal is to compare /var/adm/messages and check if the current last line is equal or not to the latest line that was checked.
the problem is that even if the strings are identical still the script treat them as not equal and continue to the if statement.
here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (MESSAGES, "tail -1 /var/adm/messages |" ) || die "failed to open alarms file \n$!\n\a";
open (ERRORLOG, ">>/usr/local/bin/mcdl_errors.log") || die "failed to open errorlog file \n$!\n\a";

my $last_line = `cat /usr/local/bin/line.txt`;


while (my $this_line = <MESSAGES>) {

  chomp($this_line);

  if ($this_line =~ m/inet|hyena|root/i) {

    if ($this_line ne $last_line) {

      print "$this_line\n";
      print "$last_line\n";    
      `echo $this_line > /usr/local/bin/line.txt`;

    }    
  }
} 

close (MESSAGES);
close (ERRORLOG);
```

Comment: maybe you need a chomp on $last_line ?

Comment: I tried with chomp but it doesnt help. seems like there is a diffrence between the cat and the echo

Comment: Take the second if out of the first if ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that perl string comparisons work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. i tried to put the second if before the first one but nothing change in the script behavior.

Comment: You do know that `ne` is *not equal* right?

Comment: yes, of course. this is what i want. if the last_line doesnt match this_line enter the if. as i said before seems like that cat and echo change the string (add blanks) and thats why it's not equal also its the same line in var/adm/messages.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix?  There could be line ending issues if you're working on Windows.  You should show us the sample output you're getting.  You should print `$this_line` and `$last_line` with marker characters before and after so that you can tell what's really in them more easily (`print "this = [[$this_line]]\n";` for example).  You should consider running the output through a hex dump program so you can inspect invisible (control) characters in the strings.

Comment: Hi, i added double quotation marks to $this_line in the echo command as Colin Phipps suggested and it solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Issue 1: You need to chomp $last_line (echo will add a \n) as someone already pointed out.

Issue 2: Passing an unquoted string on a command line will cause the shell to parse it, which will likely lose characters that get interpreted by the shell (multiple spaces or tabs reduced to one space, quotes removed etc). When that happens, the last_line that you read in next time will not match the line in the log anymore.

Issue 3: Passing an untrusted string to the shell is a very bad idea as it is easy for an attacker to inject an extra command to run into the string and hence gain unauthorised access. Passing log strings to a shell unescaped is very dangerous.

All in all, you would be much better off writing line.txt using perl file operations rather than the shell.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. how do i pass this_line  with perl to line.txt and read to last_line from line.txt?

Comment: @user2131714: consider having Perl open the file, write the string to the file, close the file.  It won't be slower than launching a shell to run echo (because that ends up running the shell as well as opening the file, writing to it, and closing the file).

Comment: Writing to a file is a simple task in perl, it should be easy to take any example from a perl book or tutorial and adapt it http://perlmaven.com/writing-to-files-with-perl

Comment: @Colin Phipps: Thanks for the tip, i changed the script to read and write using perl only.